# unable to start vncserver on centos 6

Tags: vncserver

I am trying to start vncserver with the following command--

```
/sbin/service vncserver start
```

This is the error I am getting--

```
Starting VNC server: no displays configured
```

How do I setup vncserver correctly?

Answer (score 6):

Easy steps to confgure VNC:

1. Create a user (e.g., user1).
2. Edit the `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers` file. Enter the below entry in the file.

   ```
   VNCSERVERS="2:user1"
   VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -nohttpd -localhost"
   ```
3. Login through user (user1).
4. Execute `ls -la` in the user's home directory and check whether the `.vnc` directory exists.
5. If not, run the `vncpasswd` command. It will ask for a password. Give a password you want to keep.
6. Check the user home directory again for the existence of the `.vnc` directory.
7. Start the vncserver service with `service vncserver start`.

For more details, see man vncserver(1), vncpasswd(1).

Answer (score 0):

I got that error after a fresh install of Centos 6.3 i386. The issue is that /etc/sysconfig/vncservers needs to be filled out. There are some basic instructions in that file's comments. I added the following:

```
VNCSERVERS="2:jrb"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -localhost"
```

After doing that I could start the server but there are some other steps before you can get going. I found out how to do this and the remaining configuration at http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server